# RecyclerView that implements OnItemTouchListener with views that implement OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView` implements `OnItemTouchListener` so I can grab `OnClick` events on the `RecyclerView` (allowing me to determine which `RecyclerView` cell was tapped)

Each `RecyclerView` 'cell' holds subviews that make use of `OnClickListener`

Problem:
Once one of the subview's `OnClick` is being triggered, the `RecyclerView` also thinks I tapped the whole cell

How can I make the subview catch the click event and stop propagating it to it's parent (or actually it's grandfather..) ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a common problem with list view which is why recyclerview does not provide a click listener for items.

Not sure which RecyclerView library you are using that provides clicks but this looks like a problem with that library where it does not implement onInterceptTouch / onTouch methods properly.

Instead of doing this, just set your listeners in `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: What listeners? you mean instead of implementing OnItemTouchListener I'll just have to set an OnClickListener on onCreateViewHolder on the view which is being created?

Comment: yes. If your adapter is generic etc, just pass your click listener as a parameter to your adapter and use it in onCreateVH via
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);

Comment: I've added an onclicklistener but it does not seem to work. I click the cell and OnClick is not being fired - ideas?

Comment: Share your layouts and adapter. Maybe something else is covering your view or it is not clickable.